# How to find where binutils is installed on centOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum, binutils

I used the following commands to install binutils on centOS 7:

```
$ sudo yum install binutils
Package binutils-2.27-28.base.el7_5.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Then I query where it's installed by

```
$ rpm -q binutils
binutils-2.27-28.base.el7_5.1.x86_64
```

But I still don't know where it's installed. How do I find where it installed?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-determining-finding-path-that-yum-package-installed-to/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some thing like this

```
rpm -ql binutils-2.27-28.base.el7_5.1.x86_64
```

The general command to find where is the package is installed is

```
rpm -ql <package>
```

Comment: I tried this but the output is like
```
/usr/bin/addr2line
/usr/bin/ar
/usr/bin/as
/usr/bin/c++filt
/usr/bin/dwp
/usr/bin/elfedit
/usr/bin/gprof
/usr/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld.bfd
/usr/bin/ld.gold
/usr/bin/nm
/usr/bin/objcopy
/usr/bin/objdump
/usr/bin/ranlib
/usr/bin/readelf
/usr/bin/size
/usr/bin/strings
/usr/bin/strip
/usr/lib64/libbfd-2.27-28.base.el7_5.1.so
/usr/lib64/libopcodes-2.27-28.base.el7_5.1.so
....
```
Nothing looks like the binutils package.

Comment: That's because binutils is a collection of all those files, binutils is not a file it's a name of a collection of files

Answer (score 2):

To find out the location where all the files are installed for a given packagename
you can use:

```
rpm -ql package_name
```

It basically lists all the files that are installed on your system using the required package name. So it gives the complete plath for the files that the package has installed on your system.

Comment: How is this different from the answer four hours before it?